# Thymeleaf não encontra resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estou criando um projeto com *Springboot* e *Thymeleaf*.
Configurei todo o projeto, encontro o template e as paginas, so que meu template não consegue encontrar os arquivos *css* e *js*;

Html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
```

application.properties

```
# --- CONFIGURAÇÃO TYMELEAF ---
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
```

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
             registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                     .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/static/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/static/**")
                     .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/**")
                     .addResourceLocations("/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/**");
     }
```

Estrutura de pastas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você esta utilizando o spring boot, então ele simplifica as coisas para você e já deixa acesso externo automaticamente a pasta static/, além de outras conforme a documentação.

> While this may not be a new revelation to those of you that have been following Spring Boot since the SpringOne announcement, there is one detail for which you may not be aware. Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:
>
> - /META-INF/resources/
> - /resources/
> - /static/
> - /public/

[Spring Boot Documentação](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

Dentro na pasta src/main/resources/static/:

```html
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" th:src="@{/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>

<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet"  />
```